# Find does not return all results when executed from within subdirectory

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

When using a simple `find` command like this:

`find /volume6/Misc \( -name *.rar -o -name *.zip -o -name *.7z \)`

If I execute this from the root directory (where `volume6` is) the command returns all of the expected results, but if I execute the same command from within `/volume6/Misc/` it suddenly only returns a 5-6 results instead of the 100+ I got when executed from the root directory.

If I am explicitly referencing the path as starting from the root with my leading `/`, why would the `find` command return fewer results when executed from directory A vs directory B? Its searching the same location either way.

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious: the 100+ results you get when you search from root *are* in the Misc directory, right? Also, have you tried adding a trailing slash after Misc in the `find`  command?

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the fact that when using wildcards, the `*` is evaluated first unless it is enclosed in quotations. Changing my command to:

`find /volume6/Misc \( -name "*.rar" -o -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.7z" \)`

returns the correct number of results regardless of starting location.